# Can't bind json Array to form value field

Tags: angularjs, json

i have data  like  this:

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "organizationName": "psda",
        "organizationNameEN": "psda",
},
{
        "id": 1,
        "organizationName": "psda",
        "organizationNameEN": "psda",
}]
```

and   i want tvalues, this  data  to  my table field  values , here  is  my code:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in arr" >
                <tr>
                    <td><input style="width:25px; height:25px;" type="checkbox" ng-model="chekselct"                                                     
                                                                cam-variable-name="isItemSelected"                                                  
                                                                cam-variable-type="Boolean" /></td> 
                    <td><input style="width:140px;" type="text" id="id" value= "{{item.id}}" readonly /></td>
                    <td><input style="width:305px;" type="text" id="organizationNameEN"   value="{{item.organizationName}}" readonly/></td>
<td><input style="width:305px;" type="text" id="organizationNameEN"   value="{{item.organizationName}}" readonly/></td>                     
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:25px">details</button></td>             
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

AND  IT TROWS EXCEPTION  Cannot read property 'value' of undefined,
WHAT  SHOULD  I  CHANGE  TO MAKE  THIS  CODE  WORK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of value attribute on input try ng-model

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in arr" >
                <tr>
                    <td><input style="width:25px; height:25px;" type="checkbox" ng-model="chekselct"                                                     
                                                                cam-variable-name="isItemSelected"                                                  
                                                                cam-variable-type="Boolean" /></td> 
                    <td><input style="width:140px;" type="text" id="id" ng-model="item.id" readonly /></td>
                    <td><input style="width:305px;" type="text" id="organizationNameEN"  ng-model="item.organizationName" readonly/></td>
<td><input style="width:305px;" type="text" id="organizationNameEN"   ng-model="item.organizationNameEN" readonly/></td>                     
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:25px">details</button></td>             
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: use  ng-model instead of value in your input tags

Comment: you could also use ng-value but ng-model takes care of all